# Unable to access Azure Hosted cloud service from Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, azure

I have deployed a azure cloud service on windows azure. I am able to access this cloud service in IE ,Firefox. But I get the following error when I browse using chrome. Is there any configuration that we need to be update on azure portal.

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Application is working fine in other browsers hence there is no issue with application/database. Has anyone come across this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Honestly, this doesn't sound like a programming question. And... you haven't provided any details whatsoever regarding the cloud service in question, so even if it *were* programming-related, nobody can even see exactly what's happening.

Comment: I mean what kind of details are you looking..please let me know whats needed for this. based on the error if someone faced this issue could answer.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to this issue is it could be a chrome extension that is causing this problem. Try opening azure portal in incognito mode, it might resolve the issue, if not, paste chrome://extensions in chrome's address bar, disable extensions and retry.

Answer (score -3):

Try to reset browser settings to default and clean the browser cache including history and all temp files.